# Compare two objects with the same property but it's mix together not follow a alphabet rule

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

In case I have two objects:

```
const a = {
   sample: 'this is sample',
   errorMessage: 'status is error'
}

const b = {
   errorMessage: 'status is error'
   sample: 'this is sample',
}
```

I know how to sort property by sort keys of object but **don't** know how to parse that into an object.

Example:

```
const sortA = JSON.stringify(Object.keys(a).sort) 
const sortB = JSON.stringify(Object.keys(b).sort)

expected(sortA).toEquals(sortB)
```

Comment: `Object.keys(a).sort` Does not sort an object by it's keys.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the entries of the object, sort by key, get JSON and compare the strings.

This works for not nested objects only.

```js
const
    sortBy = k => (a, b) => a[k].localeCompare(b[k]),
    a = { sample: 'this is sample', errorMessage: 'status is error' },
    b = { errorMessage: 'status is error', sample: 'this is sample' },
    sortA = JSON.stringify(Object.entries(a).sort(sortBy(0))),
    sortB = JSON.stringify(Object.entries(b).sort(sortBy(0)));

console.log(sortA === sortB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `toEqual` for that object comparison:

```
expected(sortA).toEqual(sortB)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should instead create a function that does that :

```js
const a = {
   sample: 'this is sample',
   errorMessage: 'status is error',
};

const b = {
   errorMessage: 'status is error',
   sample: 'this is sample',
};

const c = {
   errorMessage: 'status is error !',
   sample: 'this is sample',
};

const compare = (ob1, ob2) => 
  Object.keys(ob1).length === Object.keys(ob2).length
  && !Object.keys(ob1).some(key => ob2[key] !== ob1[key]);
  
  console.log(compare(a, b));
  console.log(compare(a, c));
```